# Converting hibernate entities, using a pojo that will be composed of numerous entites of different types

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have `ComplexCustomerResponse` (not persisted), it is composed of data from various sources - `CheeseEntity`, `EmployeeEntity`, `VehicleEntity`. The entities are hibernate entities and shared across multiple projects.

To map/convert the data, I want to create a TemporaryHoldingObject that will look like:

```
temporaryHoldingObject.setCheeseEntity();
temporaryHoldingObject.setEmployeeEntity();
temporaryHoldingObject.setVehicleEntity();
```

And have nothing else in it, is there a correct design pattern/name for this object?

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe it is a *[Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)*.